# Sending form data with Post while telling the server not to send a response

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

I’m posting form data using the fetch api to a web server which I don’t have control over. However, I don’t need the page in the response that the server sends back. Since I’m doing a lot of requests, I don’t want to overload the server.

Is it possible to tell the server to not send back the whole page in the response when making the request?

Comment: How will you know the call succeeded without a response confirming so from the server?

Comment: Yes you’re right. What I don’t want is to receive the entire page, which is what currently happens.

Comment: Tell the server to send back just a response code with no body then! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: HTTP is request-response protocol, this goes against the very foundation of. You can ignore the response that you get, but the server will respond to a request. If you had control over the server than you could accept a http query and only respond with minimal Ok response.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

No. You the easiest thing to do would be to leverage HTTP Response Codes (see these [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)) to respond to a request and send little or no body along with it.

In `express.js` this would be doing:

```
router.post('/add', (req,res,next) => {
   // Do logic-y things
   // if success
   res.sendStatus(200)
   // else
   res.sendStatus(500) // (or 400, or 403, or any other code that applies)
})
```